# Получение значения переменной вне функции

Tags: jquery

Есть такая функция:

```
function getData(name) {
    var username = name + '_12345';
    return username;
}
```

Мне нужно вывести значение `username` вне функции, так:

```
var username = getData('Alex');
```

Но `username` возвращает `undefined`.

Вопрос: как можно получить значение переменной `username` за пределами функции (внутри которой она объявлена)?

Comment: могу поспорить внутри _getData_ асинхронная операция

Answer (score 3):

Даже не знаю, что написать.

```js
function getData(name) {
    var username = name + '_12345';
    return username;
}

var username = getData('Alex');
console.log(username);
```

Comment: Значит, у меня по всей видимости проблема с PHP. `var image = getImageURL('<?php echo iataToCity($item['destination'], 'en');?>');
          $('#image-link').parent('.card-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, нет, проблема не с php, а с реализацией `getImageURL`. Добавь ее в вопрос